# How do I receive an alert message indicating that persistent undo will be ignored?

Tags: vimrc, undo-redo

I am using Vim 7.4. According to vim's help on persistent undo:

```
An undo file is also ignored if its owner differs from the owner of the edited file. 
Set 'verbose' to get a message about that when opening a file.
```

Where do I set `verbose`? In my vimrc I have the following as my persistent undo-related code:

```
if has("persistent_undo")
  if isdirectory(expand("~/.vim/temp_dirs/undodir"))
    verbose set undodir=~/.vim/temp_dirs/undodir
  else
    echomsg "ERROR: undodir does not exist or is not writable."
  endif

  verbose set undofile
endif
```

However, when I edit a file of which I am not the owner, I get no such message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence

```
Set 'verbose' to get a message about that when opening a file.
```

Refers to the *option* `verbose`—you can tell because it's enclosed in single-quotes, and if you place your cursor on it and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>]</kbd>, you jump to the same section as `:help 'verbose'` would.

It's not clear what level of verbosity you would need, but try

```
set verbose=1
```

and then increase from there.